# Send email on paypal success

Tags: wordpress, paypal-sandbox

I want to send an email when user paid successfully with the PayPal details. So when there is response from PayPal it should send formatted email.

Comment: Is this WooCommerce?

Comment: Its custom form

Comment: What is "custom form"?   You'll need to add more information to get a response.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is WooCommerce...

You should be able to configure an email to be sent to you via the WooCommerce emails:

```
[your-site-url]/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=email
```

For physical products, that would be order processing email.   For virtual, that is probably order completed.